# Possible failure because of sub-subprocess

Tags: subprocess, imagemagick, racket

I am new to Racket and I met a problem when trying to call an external process.

So I want to convert a pdf file to a png file using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), I have defined my arguments,

```
  (define convert-args
    (list "-density" "100")
          (dvi-file)
          "-quality" "90"
          (png-file)))
```

then I try to call `convert` using the following code:

```
(apply system*/exit-code (convert-path) convert-args)
```

I have checked the command I assembled, it's `/usr/local/bin/convert -density 100 file.pdf -quality 90 file.png`, when I copy-paste it into command-line, it worked perfectly. However, if I run this command with Racket, it will give this error:

> convert: FailedToExecuteCommand `'gs'...

I found that `gs` means [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/), which is

> An interpreter for the PostScript language and for PDF

so I am thinking, the reason why Racket gives me this error is that `convert` trying to call `gs`, but `convert` is a subprocess and `gs` is another process, somehow the subprocess cannot call a sub-subprocess, is that correct? If so, can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is typical when running via Imagick as well. The solution is usually to modify the ImageMagick delegates.xml file to replace "gs" with the full path to "gs" in the various lines that use "gs" where it shows `command="&quot;gs&quot;`. You should be able to find the path to gs via `which gs` or `type gs` on a Unix system

Comment: Thank you! @fmw42